# Want to enable only first option in dropdown and disable other options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down, in that I have first option "Select All" and other options. So if I select "Select All", I want to disable all other options, but as soon as I remove "Select All" option then all other options should be selectable.

Comment: ask a proper question, write what you tried and what the issue you are getting. you will get a good response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need this code

```
$('#mydropdwon').change(function(){
if($('#mydropdwon').val() == "Select All"){

        $(".myoptins").not($(".all")).prop('disabled', function(i, a) { return !a; });
    }
});
```

Working solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z89nmkxy/)

Please let me know if it helps.

But I would recommend you to have move select All out of drop down, you can enable/disable dropdown based on that checkbox, just for intuitiveness.

Comment: Yes Its help me.Thank you.